# What drive would have better performance for paging in this situation?

Tags: windows, performance, pagefile

Pretext: I'm re-installing my system, with an un-attended install, and I'm moving my users directory to another drive.

Question: I'm wondering where would I see more performance? Should I keep my page file on the primary drive, with windows, or should I move it to the other drive along with the users directory. or should I just turn paging off alltogehter (or at least way down) as I have 8GB of ram?

Theory: As far as I understand the hole reason you may see a performance gain from moving the pagefile off the primary drive, is because its not competing for reads/writes but I do believe the Users directory (being appData, and whatnot is located in there) is writen/read from much more often then the programs/windows directories. thought the ProgramData folder will still be on the primary drive. What do you think superusers?

Other notes:

- Running dual raid 0. Boot raid is 10000rpm (150gb raptor), secondary
  raid is 7200rpm(500gb WD's)
- 8GB of ram.
- and I was running 1GB stick as readyboost.
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64x.

Comment: See [Page File - Why set one for each drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/36721/page-file-why-set-one-for-each-drive) and [Any reason not to disable the Windows pagefile given enough physical RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/30345/any-reason-not-to-disable-the-windows-pagefile-given-enough-physical-ram) and [Windows Swap (Page File): Enable or Disable?](http://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it on the Raptors. Higher RPM = lower seek time = more IOPS = more random reads/writes on your page file.

If the drives were of equal RPM, I'd say to put the page file on the other set.

Do NOT disable your pagefile. There are many religious wars about this, but keeping it on is the correct way to do things.